# ActionView::MissingTemplate in Devise/sessions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, devise, partial-views, render

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Devise/sessions#new

Showing /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #36 raised:

Missing partial devise/sessions/rightsidediv with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/app/views", "/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/devise-1.4.2/app/views"
```

I have this in application.html.erb :

```
<%= render :partial => "rightsidediv" %>
```

The _rightsidedive.html.erb is in /views/posts/

Answer (score -1):

add the path to your include:

```
<%= render :partial => "/views/posts/rightsidediv" %>
```

Comment: This isn't the proper way to render a partial. You simply write <%= render "partialName" %> You just need to make sure your partials are in the right place.